# Add asp Code to DNN Page?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am very new to DotNetNuke. I did some development separately in Visual Studio. I just want to copy over the grid view code that I created onto an existing DNN page. When I used WordPress I simply got a PHP plug-in so that it could read the code when I added it to a page.

Comment: Haven't worked in DNN in years, but I think you'll need to create a module to do that, and then load the module onto the page.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into modules now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out these templates to get you started building modules:

https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you. I will check these out tonight.

Comment: these templates are designed fro the DNN 7.1 and newer versions.  If you have to work with an older instance it will take some configuration to get it to work.  But I highly suggest following the videos listed on the webpage: http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/aid/1 to get your development environment set up.

Comment: you can have a full development environment and your first test module set up within an hour, if you don't hit any bugs.

Comment: Will do. I am on 7.01. Is that what you meant?